# Windows service not showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-services, setup-project

I have a windows service project that I inherited and need to migrate it to a new server. I have made changes to some code, and so I created a new setup project in VS 2017. I added the .exe of the service to the set up package, and rebuilt both the service and the setup projects. When I run the .msi it seems to complete installation but when I look in the Windows Services list it's not there. What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The installer probably didn't run the installutil.exe program.

You can do this manually by dropping to a command prompt then navigating to the location that the installer put the .exe file.  From there run this:

```
installutil.exe myservice.exe
```

where myservice is the exe file you generated.

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool

Also, you might need to add the installutil.exe path.  It's part of the .net framework and will be found in that install directory.